# G-invariant subset map is invertible

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

$X$ is a $G$-set, and $Y$ is a $G$-invariant subset of $X$, which means that $g(Y) = Y$ for every $g \in G.$ For a given $g \in G$, let us consider the map
$r[g] (y) = g \cdot y.$

How do I show that $r[g]$ is invertible for a fixed $g$?

Comment: If you know what a group and a group action are, then you should know what the inverse of $r[g]$ is...

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** You want $h \in G$ such that $h(gx) = x$.  Note $h(gx) = (hg)x$, so what should $hg$ be such that it doesn't move anything?

Comment: It should be an identity and thus h becomes an inverse of g. The problem is I am having difficulty in understanding this notation **r[g](y)=g⋅y** and how to use this to formulate the solution.

Comment: $r[g]$ is just the name of a function, so the notation $r[g](y)$ is just like the notation $f(y)$ where your function $f$ is $r[g]$.

Comment: To use it to solve the problem, maybe you should prove that for any $g, h \in G$ then as functions you have $r[g]\circ r[h] = r[gh]$.